# filling list, but getting Object refrence error for bind dropdownlist in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dropdownlistfor

I am using below code to bind the dropdownlist, i am not getting why i am getting object reference error, even i initialized the entity.

```
public class RankingEntity
{
    public string Tournament { get; set; }
    public IList<SelectListItem> Years { get; set; }
}

public class Years
{
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public string YearDisplay { get; set; }
}
```

Controller's code:

```
 public ActionResult Index()
    {

        var years = _rankingService.GetAllYears().ToList();

        var model = new RankingEntity();
        if (years != null)
        {
            foreach (var y in years)
            {
                model.Years.Add(new SelectListItem
                {
                    Text = y.Year.ToString(),
                    Value = y.Year.ToString()
                });
            }
        }
        return View(model);
    }
```

I am getting error on `model.Years.Add(new SelectListItem` i.e. "**Object reference**"

please correct me,

Comment: Because you have not initialized `Years` - `model.Years = new List<SelectListItem>();`

Comment: Make sure model.Years is not null, you can instantiate it before you add like  model.Years = new model.Years();

Comment: You are getting the error because Years in RankingEntity in never intialized. Simply add a constructor to instantiate it.